# Adding ticks to grid plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot, grid

It is a rather simple question but I am struggling to figure it out.
Below I created a grid and have some points that I plot on it.
How do I add tick marks + labels (from 0 to 10 on each axis)? Also, how do I add a legend for my points?

Thanks so much in advance. Solutions or references to `ggplot2` solutions would be appreciated too.

```
# Install libraries
library(sp)
library(gstat)

# Set seed for reproducible results
set.seed = 34
x <- c(5.9,6.5,7.1,3.1,5.6,8.1,6.3,5.8,2.1,8.8,5.3,6.8,9.9,2.5,5.8,9.1,2.4,2.5,9.2)
y <- c(3.6,6.5,5.4,5.2,1.1,5.1,2.7,3.8,6.07,4.4,7.3,1.8,9.2,8.5,6.8,9.3,2.5,9.2,2.5)
attr <- c(23,56,2,34,7,89,45,34,2,34,5,67,8,99,6,65,3,32,12)
initialdata <- data.frame(x,y,attr)
colnames(initialdata) <- c("x","y","attr")

# Creating SpatialPointDataFrame:
coords <- data.frame(initialdata$x,initialdata$y)
coords <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string=CRS(as.character(NA)), bbox = NULL)
initialdata_DF <- data.frame(coords,initialdata$attr)
initialdata_SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,initialdata_DF)

#==============#
cellsize <- 1
#==============#

# Creating a grid 
bb<- bbox(coords)
cs <- c(cellsize,cellsize)
cc <- bb[,1] + (cs/2)
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)
initialdata_grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset = cc, cellsize = cs,
                                cells.dim = cd)
initialdata_SG <- SpatialGrid(initialdata_grd) # Final grid created here

# Plot the results:
plot(initialdata_SG)
plot(initialdata_SPDF, add=T,col="blue", pch="+")
```

Comment: Try with function `axis`, i.e. `axis(1,...)` for x-axis and `axis(2,...)` for y-axis. You probably will have to adjust the position of the ticks with the argument `at`.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked